# How to piece together a file splitted when there is not enough disk space

Tags: bash, gzip, tar

I was sent 194 Gb worth of data  split into 1984 files
There is only 37Gb left on my disk and there are no other disks with that amount of free space.  Obviously, this is not going to work

```
cat file.tar.gz.part*  > file.tar.gz
```

Looking for a way to incrementally piece this huge file together

I might end up writing the script myself but posting here for the community

Comment: Btw.: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 3):

We need to assume the large file was split using a naming convention

- Original file=LargeFile.bin
- Split files=(LargeFile.split.aaa, LargeFile.split.aab, ...)

The script to recover would then be:

```
outfile=LargeFile.recovered.bin
for i in LargeFile.split.* ; do
   cat ${i} >> ${outfile}
   rm -f ${i}
done
```

Simple but handy when there is not enough space to do it in one move

Comment: Btw.: [Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: hmm, I don't see any issues with using `for` here, but you should [never parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). so `for i in LargeFile.split.*; do ...; done` would be more appropriate

Comment: `outfile=LargeFile.recovered.bin
for i in LargeFile.split.*; do
   cat ${i} >> ${outfile}
   rm -f ${i}
done` would be even better :-) you don't need to use `ls`

Comment: Awesome!  I will amend accodingly